# Angular multiple modules providing same service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, injectable, angular-fontawesome

I am using a library ([FontAwesome for Angular](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/)) which provides two services under the same name:

Lets say the first one is the *real* one:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Service { }

@NgModule({
  exports: [...],
})
export class Module {}
```

and the second one provides a mock version

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MockService implements Service { }

@NgModule({
  exports: [...],
  provide: [{ provide: Service, useExisting: MockService }],
})
export class MockModule {}
```

Normally you would either use `Module` or `MockModule`.
I now ran into a case where I would like to use both of them (arguably not very smart but it is in some util testing modules to reduce boilerplate code).

Is it possible to import `Module` and `MockModule` but having access to the actual `Service` and not the mock implementation `MockService`?
So far I played around with the order of the modules but any order results in the `MockService` being injected.

Would a change in the services from `providedIn: 'root'` to instead provide them in the module directly make this possible or is there any other way to get access to the *real* service again?

Comment: As you suggest `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})` is incompatible with your scenario. Remove the configuration from the decorator and explicitly register the service in question

Comment: Thanks for the input, I guess I will have to open a PR for the library then.

Comment: That's probably a good idea, but why not override the registration in your own app module's config?

Comment: The modules are also provided by the Library. So I cannot change how the services are provided.